# How to display Gujarati text from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a SQLite database which is in Gujarati language. When I show data from this database in my app, it appears as some garbage characters (some boxes or rectangles). I am using the following code to set the Gujarati font in my app;

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FontName.ttf");

buttonsetTypeface(typeface);
button.setText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(a[i]).trim());
```

What do I have to do so that the text appears properly in Gujarati?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your android phone has to be setup to support the language.
Apparently the [language code](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) is 'gu' if that helps.